# Make a play within time limit in C

Tags: c, time

Well, as the title suggests, I am coding a game which is called Morabaraba. It will be a computer vs human game. I will use game trees and alpha-beta cut-offs in order to generate the computer plays and every computer play should be made in a specific amount of time (let's say 15 seconds).

What is the best way to count the elapsed seconds since the begin of its turn and validate that it still has not exceeded the time limit without overloading the system? As is known, time is precious when generating game trees. Exceeding time limit will result in forfeit.

I want to know how this could be done with lightweight algorithm. How can I validate that time limit has not been reached every x seconds? Is the time of this validation negligible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your target environment? There are no portable interrupt timers -- which is what you need for a lightweight (speedwise) implementation.

Comment: Also, if you just cut off a depth-first search when you run out of time, your program will play poorly. Consider at least partially breadth-first algorithms.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm programming in linux

Comment: @JimBalter I'm considering doing a shallow search first if that is what you mean

Comment: See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: ... you can use that to invoke a routine (a signal catcher) every time some interval has elapsed. Have the routine decrement a variable that contains how much time you have left to play. You can check the variable from anywhere in your program with no overhead. On search, it sounds like you're talking about iterative deepening ... see http://www.cs.unm.edu/~aaron/downloads/qian_search.pdf for that and other ideas.

Comment: Indeed, I was referring to iterative deepening... Still learning about the topic, definitely will do more research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, time of this validation will be mostly negligible just because you will poll the amount of time passed at discrete intervals and compare it to the start time to know how much time is elapsed so far.

I see two solutions here:

- embed the time check in the same thread that is computing the alpha-beta pruning and stop it accordingly returning the best solution found so far
- place the AI code on a separate thread and interrupt it when time went over a threshold, by ensuring that the best solution so far is already stored somewhere so that you can pick it up

Second approach may sound scary but in certain situations it's just unpractical to check elapsed time within the algorithm itself because the code cannot be easily adapted and interrupted from the callee (for example if you have a non modular algorithm made of many different steps, which is not your case though)

Comment: How would you "poll the amount of time passed at discrete intervals"? Could you please post some code?

Comment: You save the start time somewhere with something like `clock_t startTime = clock()`. Then every time you want to know the total amount you do `clock_t elapsed = clock() - startTime` and do what you need to do accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Start by just checking the time after every "step" or every N steps, in some way that you believe you are checking at least once a second.  If the nature of your computation makes this impractical, you can use something like POSIX timers to signal your process when a given amount of time has passed.

Comment: As I will be generating nodes and making alpha-beta cuts the time would be very variant even though a tree depth may be specified